# Making and updating score system in python (out of function)

Tags: python-3.x

first of all, I'm new to Python.

I want to increase "humanscore" or "computerscore" in win and lose conditions.

This increase occurs in the win and lose functions, that is, +1 is added to the variables, but it becomes 0 again when you switch to the other function.

```
import random
R = "ROCK"
P = "PAPER"
S = "SCİSSORS"
print("Welcome to 'Rock Paper Scissors' game!\n")

humanscore = 0
computerscore = 0

def end():
    print("\n\n\n\n\n")
    print("Computer's weapon =", computer)
    print("Your weapon =", human, "\n\n\n")

def win(humanscore):
    print("You win!")
    humanscore += 1
    return humanscore

def lose(computerscore):
    print("You lose!")
    computerscore += 1
    return computerscore

def Score(humanscore, computerscore):
    score = (f"Human Score = {humanscore}, Computer Score = {computerscore}")
    print(score)


while True:
    allweapon = (R, P, S)
    computer = random.choice(allweapon)
    print(f"1. {R}\n2. {P}\n3. {S}\n")
    human = str.upper(input("Choose your weapon!\n"))

    if human == R:
        if computer == S and human == R:
            end()
            win(humanscore)
            Score(humanscore, computerscore)
        elif computer == P and human == R:
            end()
            lose(computerscore)
            Score(humanscore, computerscore)
    if human == S:
        if computer == P and human == S:
            end()
            win(humanscore)
            Score(humanscore, computerscore)

        elif computer == R and human == S:
            end()
            lose(computerscore)
            Score(humanscore, computerscore)
    if human == P:
        if computer == S and human == P:
            end()
            lose(computerscore)
            Score(humanscore, computerscore)
        elif computer == R and human == P:
            end()
            win(humanscore)
            Score(humanscore, computerscore)
    if human == computer:
        end()
        Score(humanscore, computerscore)
        print("Tied!")
    if human != R:
        print("There is no such weapon!\n")
```

I want to increase the score system properly.